# Trouble aiming the selfie

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I seem so have some trouble correctly lining up selfies in GTA V. For example, I'll first position myself as I would in real life*, with the subject (somewhat) behind me, so I can get both my head and it in the frame.
But then when I open the camera, my character seems to have turned around. So I try again, this time facing the subject, but he'll be positioned the same way! And at other times, it's the other way around.

Is it just awkward or am I doing something wrong. Does collision with other characters/walls matter?

What's the true righteous way of lining up selfies?

*Not that I take that many selfies :]

Comment: While writing I realized I haven't actually paid attention to the orientation of the third-person camera, so I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to make a difference either. I did notice that if you turn around in non-selfie camera mode, it will affect the orientation of the character when you switch, but in a non-deterministic way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you move the phone (in-game)..

Try to just move the phone around (in camera, front-facing mode) using the thumbsticks... That's what worked for me.